# Posts white-out after browser tab has been open for a while

Tags: bug, posts, caching

I've noticed some strange behavior a lot lately. In *Safari*, if I leave a tab open to a *StackOverflow* post for a while, then navigate back to it, parts of the post are whited-out. Is this a web browser caching bug - or something with the SO web code?

Scrolling up and down seems to change what is whited out, as does clicking on the whited out areas. Here is an example image:

[image: page whited out]

Comment: Most likely a browser/computer issue with repaints. What happens when you minimize then restore the window?

Comment: This happens to me as well, SO is the only site I've seen it happen on and it happens fairly frequently. Also using Safari.

Comment: It's a Safari bug. I've seen it across a bunch of websites, so there's probably nothing SE can do about it (except forcing repaints).